# Mandelbrot CUDA GPU

Tags: header, gpu

I'd appreciate if you help me to understand how should read and understand this error. I'd like to learn how to fix program by troubleshooting.

Severity

Code

Description

Project

File

Line

Suppression State

Error

MSB3721

`The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing`

> Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc.exe"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2015 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"c:\Users\rezaaa\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\example11\packages\nupengl.core.0.1.0.1\build\native../..//build/native/include/"
>   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\Mandelbrot_cuda.cu.obj "c:\Users\rezaa\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples\2_Graphics\Mandelbrot\Mandelbrot_cuda.cu""
>   exited with code 2.

```
example11 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
8.0.targets 687
```

Comment: It means essentially nothing, it gives no information except that there was an error in the compiler.

Comment: Error
C1083
Cannot open include file: 'helper_cuda.h': No such file or directory
@Natecat example11
c:\Users\rezaa\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples\2_Graphics\Mandelbrot\Mandelbrot_cuda.cu
13

Comment: But I have this file in directory  of my solution explorer !

Comment: @Natecat Were above comments helpful for troubleshooting?